# How to find all strings from a list of strings that do NOT appear in any of my source files?

Tags: code-cleanup

I've got a bit of a messy DB. There are a lot of stored procedures that I strongly suspect are not used. I can easily get all their names in a text file, one name per line. Now I would like to search all through my code files to find which ones are mentioned and, more importantly, which ones are not.

How could I do such a thing? I'm using Windows 7, Visual Studio 2008 - if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own small app (console app would do).
read your file, get the procedure-names inside a list, and then for each name search your code file, and log the name if  you did not find the nam einside your code-files.

See System.IO.FileStream class for the easy (but not that fast) way of search a file.

Comment: I know I can do that. I was wondering if there is something already premade, so I don't have to spend my time writing that program.

Comment: VS itself does not support such an advanced search mechanism, but you could search for an vs-add-in, that can do more advanced searches. but i doubt that you will find one that will satisfy your needs. [link](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/)

Comment: I know it does not support it, else I wouldn't ask this question. I'm looking for 3rd party utilities (or plugins, or whatever) that do this. However I guess you're right. The task is so trivial, that it's faster to write my own app than to look for an existing one.